# Fantasy novel featuring a female lead with a skeleton and chimera characters

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the name of this fantasy novel I read in the 90's. I can't remember too much about it, but I believe there was a female lead with a skeleton and chimera characters. I recall one scene in general where the girl is having an argument about syntax/sin tax. Any help is appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: Almost anytime that you have wordplay/puns like syntax/sin tax your first best bet is to look at the Xanth series by PierS ANTHony (Santh/Xanth). Another secondary choice is the Myth series by Robert Asprin.

Comment: God bless the internet, thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! To indicate that a post fully answers your question, please [mark it as accepted](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like it might be [Harpy Thyme](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0812534840), from Piers Anthony's *Xanth* series.

The main character is Gloha, a hybrid between a harpy and a goblin.  While I don't believe there's a chimera in it, there are skeletons (from the realm of bad dreams, although some, like Marrow Bones, are friendly), and there is a discussion about a sin tax (collected by a Sin Bursar, and Gloha confuses it for "syntax"; Xanth is based largely on puns).

Answer (score 5):

[Harpy Thyme](http://books.google.com/books?id=ntVphkJgXpgC&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=piers%20anthony%20syntax%20sin%20tax&source=bl&ots=zbBJb1QZWb&sig=moklAwSRdKlrumNenvD9hadh6sk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XiImUry1H9K4yAGIuYG4Aw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=piers%20anthony%20syntax%20sin%20tax&f=false) by Piers Anthony in the Xanth series.